# What is the difference in the process of publishing a post from the Wordpress admin panel and from the frontend?

Tags: php, wordpress

My function is to create a unique number in the custom field of each "doc" type post.
If the custom field of the saved post is empty, the function increments and saves the number stored in the title of the post with the specific id. The function then writes this number to the custom field of the saved post.
This works if I create a post from the WordPress admin panel. But if I create a post from the frontend using the ACF Frontend plugin, then only the number in the title of the post with the id changes, and the number is not written to the custom field of the saved post.
What is the difference between these ways to save a post? How I can track at what point the algorithm stops working?

```
add_action('save_post', 'update_doc_num', 10, 3);
function update_doc_num($post_id, $post, $update) {
    if ($post->post_type === 'doc' && empty(get_post_meta($post_id, 'doc_num', true))) {
        $source_post_id = 1137;
        $source_post = get_post($source_post_id);
        $current_title = $source_post->post_title;
        $current_number = intval($current_title);
        $new_number = $current_number + 1;
        $new_number = strval($new_number);
        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID' => $source_post_id,
            'post_title' => $new_number
        ));
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'doc_num', $new_number);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not be using `update_post_meta` to set ACF values, but https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/ instead. ACF itself records more than just the `fieldname=value` record in the meta data table, it adds a second record that uses the internal ACF field key. `update_post_meta` will not create the latter.